# C++ Function taking picture box

Tags: c++, function, picturebox

I am trying to make a function that takes a picture box for a parameter. How do i do that?

Ex:

```
void functionName(picturebox a){
    if (... == ...){
        a->Load("filePath")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error, is most likely coming from your picture box being copied.

Seeing how the function returns void, you intend to edit picturebox but are passing it by value which invokes the copy constructor and creates a new temp object for that function call.

If this is the problem, try passing the picturebox object by reference.

```
void functionName(picturebox& a){
    if (... == ...){
        a->Load("filePath")
    }
}
```